# Flutter HLS .m3u8 video not playing in real time

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, http-live-streaming

I have a .m3u8 video URL that works perfectly when played on a browser player and continously shows the live video.

However with video_player on Flutter, after initializing the video controller, only about 20 or so seconds is available in the player, and when reaching the end of it, it does not continue playing and stops playing the video as if it is a limited 20 second video.

If I want to see the next few seconds or closer to the live feed, I need to dispose and reinitalize the controller.

I don't see this issue posted anywhere so where am I going wrong?

```
videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network('https://example.com/abcdef.m3u8');

(videoPlayerController.value.isInitialized)
        ?
        Expanded(
            child: VideoPlayer(
              videoPlayerController,
            ),
          )
        : Text('Nope'),
    SizedBox(
      height: screenHeight * 0.1,
    ),
    SizedBox(
      width: screenHeight * 0.2,
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        heroTag: 'Start',
        onPressed: () async {
          await videoPlayerController.initialize();
          videoPlayerController.play();
          home.notifyListeners();
        },
        child: const Text('Start'),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: Looks like it is an issue with the library: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/115860 . I'm not sure if other libraries support `.m3u8` but you could try: https://pub.dev/packages?q=video+player

Comment: @CoderUni does this issue occures only on web browsers, the video_player dod not support playing .m3u8 links on all platforms ?

Comment: @Gwhyyy Looks like this issue only occurs on web browsers and ios 16.1+ https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/116021

Comment: @CoderUni In that case I don't understand why it's happening to me, cause I'm testing this on a real device on Android. I don't think it is the same issue I'm facing, as I don't get any Exceptions, and the video does play. Just that it only gets the video once, and so it has a limited duration and does not update as a live video should.

Comment: @Jiehfeng could you open an issue in flutter's github repo? https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3A%22p%3A+video_player%22 . Not sure why your issue is happening but I believe this is a problem with the library's support for `.m3u8` videos

Comment: @CoderUni Fixed the issue, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the reason why I have been experiencing this problem.

In my testing I have also setup RTMP streaming through the camera plugin, and I had that on while I tried to fetch the HLS video. I thought both are unrelated so it shouldn't affect anything but perhaps they both use a same library, so that's why the issue. With no streaming being done, the HLS video plays normally as expected.